# Moving legend position in base R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dose response curve I'm trying to plot in base R. Unfortunately, I get a series of errors whenever I try to move the legend to the top left of the code.

To create a dataframe:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
y <- c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

This is my current arrangement:

```
plot(df, pch="",
     col = c("Green","Black"),
     legend("topleft", legend = "legend"))
```

In this arrangement, I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (s, units = "user", cex = NULL, font = NULL, vfont = NULL,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

This error is confusing to me, because I created the plot earlier in the code.

How can I move the figure legend in a base R plot?

Comment: The legend isn't an argument to plot. It added after plotting. Try `plot(df, pch="", col = c("Green","Black"));   legend("topleft", legend = "legend")`

Comment: This works, kind of. It creates a new legend where I'd like the current one to be.

Comment: Your comment suggests you already have a legend.  You need to show us the code you used.